# How to export and import these data

Tags: export, import, list-manipulation

I want to export my_data and then import them back again in exactly the same data structure as the one they had when they were initially generated.

```
mydata = Table[{σ, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ]]}, {σ, 1, 2}, {100}]
```

I say exactly, because no matter what I have tried based on the online documentation, when I import the exported data, the structure is not valid for plotting them using:

```
Show[
 Histogram3D[
  mydata,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 20}, {0, All}},
  AxesLabel -> (Text[Style[#, Italic, 14]] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"})]
 ]
```

(plotting works with the initially generated data)

Could you provide here with the correct export and import commands?

Comment: Underscore should not appear in a Mathematica symbol. Use mydata instead of my_data.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning. Though in practice I am not using. The variable is simply "data". Hence, the question still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Put (>>) and Get (<<).

```
mydata>>filename
mydataImported = <<filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, exporting and importing as a spreadsheet

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234]
```

Generating and exporting the data

```
Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/mydata.xls",
  mydata = Table[{σ, 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, σ]]}, {σ, 1, 2}, {100}]];
```

The imported data is

```
mydata2 = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/mydata.xls"];
```

The data is equivalent

```
mydata == mydata2

(* True *)
```

Although not identical

```
mydata === mydata2

(* False *)
```

Generating the histograms

```
{hg1, hg2} = 
 Show[Histogram3D[#, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-20, 20}, {0, All}}, 
     AxesLabel -> (Text[Style[#, Italic, 14]] & /@ {"a", "b", 
         "c"})]] & /@ {mydata, mydata2}
```

[image]

The histograms are identical

```
SameQ @@ {hg1, hg2}

(* True *)
```