# Solutions for Storing Large Amounts of Data for Re-Import into Mathematica

Tags: data

## The Problem

I have a decently large amount of data that I'm performing a bunch of computation on. My typical M.O. in Mathematica is to use `Table` to generate a nested array to store my results, and then refer back to the specific columns for additional computation/plotting. Currently, generating the array takes ~40 min. on a pretty beefy personal machine, using `ParallelTable` for the computation. While prototyping additional analysis I will frequently encounter crashes or hangs which require me to restart the kernel, and perform that 40 min of computation again (which is pretty frustrating).

Ideally, I would be able to export the output of that computation as some kind of file that I could then import into Mathematica instead of having to perform the computation repeatedly. I usually use `.csv` but this data doesn't work well for that as it has nested array elements which can be vary in size (depending on the initial raw data).

### The Question

Is there a file format or storage solution that would allow me to keep my computed data as a nested array so that it can be easily imported again? For example, `matlab` has the `save` command which basically takes a snapshot of the runtime which makes recovering from a crash easy.

Alternatively, is there a better or more idiomatic solution for storing the results of my computation that I should be using?

### EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments, there are at least 3 functions for saving Mathematica objects, `Save`, `DumpSave`, and `Put`.

Timing the three options on my system indicates that `DumpSave` is the best option for me:
[image: Plot comparing the storage and retrieval time for Save, DumpSave and Put]

Additionally, `DumpSave` results in a much smaller file size compared to `Save` (~700Mb vs ~1800Mb).

It appears that the main bottleneck is retrieving the data, but it's an order of magnitude faster than repeating the computation every time the kernel crashes.

Comment: You can write the expression to a file using `DumpSave`, or `Save`. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183599/working-with-a-csv-data-file-with-100-millions-rows-and-30-columns) question might help.

Comment: Wow, I feel silly for not even having looked in the Docs for `Save`.

Comment: Try [`Put`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) and [`Get`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html) as shown in the answer to [How to export and import these data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/231239), a duplicate?

Comment: Having tried it, `Save` is extremely slow for this application (317s), and results in a 1.8 Gb file, 356s Import time. `DumpSave` does a much better job, at 71s, with a 638 Mb file, 5s Import time.

Comment: For this data, `Put` takes 193s, and `Get` takes 350s to import the object created by `Put`. So, for my application, `DumpSave` appears to be a clear winner

Comment: Actually, it appears that I can't actually `Get` or `Import` the output of `DumpSave`, which is very strange. It doesn't indicate that there's been an error, `Get` and `Import` just return empty arrays.

Comment: I got `Get` to work with the `DumpSave` archive, and it takes ~ 354s with the successful import. So, `DumpSave` is still the winner, but the limit is still retrieving the data.

Comment: Do you need to load the entire file at once? You could open a stream then just access the portions you need at any given time using `SetStreamPosition`. You might have to write the binary file yourself.

Comment: My data is a time series, and I frequently need to look at a specific metric that I've extracted (like peak position or FWHM) as a function of time, so I want to load the whole time series. I suppose if I transposed the data so that it was wide instead of tall, I could load only the metrics I was interested in (since they're currently the columns). I don't know if that would be more efficient though.